# Copy a directory and some of its content to a new directory R

Tags: r, directory

I have a lot of directories containing engineering drawings (upto a few hundred). The directory names begin with a drawing number and a description e.g. "13160001678 Evaporative cooler". The number in the directory name is the principal assembly drawing in the folder (other files are part drawings that are used in the assembly). I want to copy the folder name and only the file corresponding to the number in the folder name.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
current_directory <- "T:\\Gaveglia\\original_drawings"

new_location <- "T:\\Gaveglia\\copied_drawings"

new_names <- list.dirs(current_directory, recursive = F, full.names = F)

sapply(new_names, function(z) dir.create(file.path(new_location, z)))

dwg_names <- str_extract(string = new_names, pattern = '[[:digit:]]+')

long_dir_names <- list.dirs(current_directory, recursive = F, full.names = T)

new_subdirectories <- list.dirs(new_location, full.names = T, recursive = F)

lapply(1:length(dwg_names), function(z){
  kk <- dir(path = long_dir_names[z], 
            pattern = paste(dwg_names[z],".*PDF", "|", dwg_names[z], ".*pdf",sep = ""),
            full.names = T)
  sapply(kk, function(q){
    file.copy(from = q, to = new_subdirectories[z] )
  })
})
```

This seems to work pretty well. However, for some cases, there are several sub-folders that need to copied as well. Using the same example as above, "13160001678 Evaporative cooler" has a drawing named "13160001678.SLDASM.pdf" but also 13 folders that follow the same naming convention and are required to be copied (see below image).

[image]

I can address this by either:

1. re-running the code for the "13160001678 Evaporative cooler" folder instead of `current_directory`.
2. Modify my code to drill down to one level of sub-directories

The former is just more time consuming. I'm reluctant to implement the latter since I think it can potentially make the whole process much slower. Is there any other way to deal with this? Perhaps a package?

Comment: Can you give example of your directory tree with files and subfolders (also marked files that you want to copy)?

Comment: @PoGibas I've added an image of the contents of "13160001678 Evaporative cooler"